# ArcGIS query not working in Personal Geodatabase when OK with shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, ms-access

I have one strange problem. I have access database that fills at daily bases. I import it to arcgis and data displays normaly but I want to filter data by date. 
I write query like this : date_field > date'2018-05-20 00:00:00' and ArcGis return error missing operator, invalid sql syntaks.

When I make shapefile from that database, same query normaly works?
 Because we fill database at daily basis I want display data directly from database. Any advise?

Comment: What do you mean by import to ArcGIS? You are adding the data to ArcGIS or converting it? What is the data type of the field?

Comment: I connect to access database throught catalog. A then drag and drop table to layers.
Field is short date type

Answer (score 3):

Different geodatabase sources require different types of date queries. Take a look at this [help page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB) that shows how to form a proper date query in various geodatabases, for example an access database:

> **Personal geodatabase**
>
> Dates in personal geodatabases are delimited using a pound sign (#).
>
> For example:
>
> [Datefield] = #mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss#
>
> It can be shortened to [Datefield] = #mm-dd-yyyy#.
>
> An alternative format
>
> [Datefield] = #yyyy/mm/dd#